# MySQL Triggers: How do I only insert if a certain column is populated?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have two tables: 
1) orders
2) transactions -  which stores loyalty points against shoppers

Now in my code (PHP) I have a certain column (points - which are only entered into the orders table if the user has captured his loyalty card number, else it remains empty).

IF the points are inserted into the points column on my orders table, (in other words, if the shopper has earned points) a trigger should fire and insert a bunch of the values from the orders table (including the points) into the transactions table.

Question 1) This is an after insert.  How do I get the values from the row that was just inserted into my orders table?

Question 2) How do I make this happen only if the points column has a value?

EDIT:  The trigger will fire every time something gets inserted into the orders table, but an entry must only be made into the transaction table if there are is a value in the orders.points column.

Here are the tables:

Orders:

```
Field                Null  Key  Extra           
order_id             
user_id              NO    MUL                  
vendor_id            NO    MUL                  
order_number         YES   MUL                  
user_info_id         YES   MUL                  
order_total          NO                         
order_subtotal       YES                        
order_tax            YES                        
order_tax_details    NO                         
order_shipping       YES                        
order_shipping_tax   YES                        
coupon_discount      NO                         
coupon_code          YES                        
order_discount       NO                         
order_currency       YES                        
order_status         YES                        
cdate                YES                        
mdate                YES                        
ship_method_id       YES   MUL                  
customer_note        NO                         
ip_address           NO                         
waybill_number       YES                        
shipping_carrier_id  YES                        
shipping_location    NO                         
insurance            NO                         
points               YES                        
loyalty_card_number  YES
```

Transaction:

```
Field               Null  Key  Extra           
id                  NO    PRI  auto_increment  
transactiontypeid   NO    MUL                  
orderid             NO                         
orderstatusid_from  NO                         
orderstatusid_to    NO                         
ordervalue          NO                         
points              YES                        
loyaltycardnumber   YES                        
integrationfileid   YES                        
createduserid       NO                         
createddate         NO
```

I am pretty new at triggers (as you can see) - Thanks for your help.

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this,

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
   ON ORDER FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  // you can access your inserted row value like this
if (new.points > 0)
{
  //your insertion code goes here
}

END;
```